# Not sure what do.call() is doing here in R

Tags: r

So I'm new to R, and I'm trying to build a correlation matrix by avoiding for-loops.  I've search everywhere online and I can't seem to figure out what do.call() is doing in my particular case.  Some of you might suggest I try lapply or sapply instead, however here I would just like to understand why do.call() is working.

My initial approach was the following, easy and sub-optimal:
(Master is a data.frame with price data, with the first column being the Date, which is why I exclude it.)

```
for(i in 1:length(names(Master)[-1]))
{
  for(j in 1:length(names(Master)[-1]))
  {
    MasterVCV[i,j] <- cor(Master[,1+i],Master[,1+j],use="pairwise.complete.obs",method="pearson")
  }

}
```

However this, for some reason that I cannot figure out, also works:

```
matrix(
  data=do.call(function(X){cor(Master[,as.character(X)],Master[,as.character(X)],use="pairwise.complete.obs",method="pearson")},list(names(Master)[-1]))
  ,nrow=length(names(Master)[-1])
  ,ncol=length(names(Master)[-1])
  ,dimnames=list(names(Master)[-1],names(Master)[-1])
)
```

I'm not sure why/how it's building the pairs to create the square matrix when I'm only passing a single list.  My guess is it's doing a cross-join in the indices but I can't find any documentation anywhere.  Any help/feedback would be very much appreciated.  Please let me know if any other details are required.

Thank you,

EDIT: test case added (I hope this works and is the appropriate format) - data is downloaded from quandl

```
library(quantmod)
library(Quandl)


FFFactors <- Quandl("KFRENCH/FACTORS_D",type = "raw", start_date="2001-01-01", end_date = "2010-01-01")
MOM <-  Quandl("KFRENCH/MOMENTUM_D",type = "raw", start_date="2001-01-01", end_date = "2010-01-01")

FFFactors<-data.frame(Date=FFFactors[,1],sapply(FFFactors[,-1],function(X){X/100}))
MOM<-data.frame(Date=MOM[,1],MOM=MOM[,length(MOM)]/100)



Master<-merge(FFFactors,MOM,by.x="Date",by.y="Date",all.x=TRUE,all.y=TRUE)

#Recode and clean
Master$Curve[Master$Curve==Inf]<-NA
Master$Curve[Master$Curve==-Inf]<-NA
Master$Curve[Master$Curve==NaN]<-NA



##########ALTERNATIVE VCV CALC#############

  MasterVCV2<-
    matrix(
      data=do.call(function(X){cor(Master[,as.character(X)],Master[,as.character(X)],use="pairwise.complete.obs",method="pearson")},list(names(Master)[-1]))
      ,nrow=length(names(Master)[-1])
      ,ncol=length(names(Master)[-1])
      ,dimnames=list(names(Master)[-1],names(Master)[-1])
    )



#dimension VCV and create it
MasterVCV<-matrix(nrow=length(names(Master)[-1]),ncol=length(names(Master)[-1]),dimnames=list(names(Master)[-1],names(Master)[-1]))

  for(i in 1:length(names(Master)[-1]))
  {
    for(j in 1:length(names(Master)[-1]))
    {
      MasterVCV[i,j] <- cor(Master[,1+i],Master[,1+j],use="pairwise.complete.obs",method="pearson")
    }

  }

identical(MasterVCV,MasterVCV2)
```

Comment: Are you sure those are giving you equivalent results? What happens if you run `identical(.,.)` on the two different outputs?

Comment: they are actually (apologies I'm still trying to figure commenting out)....> identical(MasterVCV,MasterVCV2)
[1] TRUE

Comment: Then post a test case.

Answer (score 1):

So first of all, if you want a correlation matrix, you don't have to jump through all these fiery hoops (not in R at least).

```
cor(Master[,-1],use="pairwise.complete.obs",method="pearson")
```

will do it for you - e.g. if you pass a matrix to `cor(...)`, you get a correlation matrix of every column with every other column. Here we're passing all columns but the first. This is also to do with why you get the unexpected result with `do.call(...)`.

Your argument:

```
list(names(Master)[-1])
```

is a list with one element, containing a vector of all the names. So your expression:

```
do.call(function(X) {...}, list(names(Master)[-1]))
```

essentially passes a vector containing all the relevant column names to your function, which passes that on to `cor(...)` as:

```
cor(Master[,names(Master)[-1]],Master[,names(Master)[-1]],...)
```

which in turn calculates the complete correlation matrix in one step.

One final note. The expression:

```
as.list(names(Master)[-1])
```

creates a list with `ncol(Master)-1` elements, each containing the name of one column. Using that instead in `do.call(...)` would have thrown an error, because your function is not set up to take a list of arguments.

Comment: thank you!  I truly appreciate your feedback, I did not realize that I only needed one data-argument for cor()

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new to SO, please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers).